# How do i make to add a key to a object out of itself?

Tags: javascript, object, key, addition

I have an object that represents the inventory of a discord user:

`if (!userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].money) userData[sender.id + message.guild.id].inventory = {};`

This code "asks" if, in the file, I use as a DataBase (a `.json` file, by the way), have the object of the inventory, and, if not, he creates the object.

I want to add a key to this object as soon as the user bought something at my bot's store (of course, it's not a real store, I'm making an economy system for my bot). The key would be something like:

`..."inventory": { "1": "melon", "2": "apple" }`

BTW, the "..." it is because there are some things before, and the `"1"`, `"2"`, it is the example keys, they represent the items that the user has bought.

Comment: `....inventory.3 = "banana"` or with AlphaNumeric keys `....inventory[key] = "banana"`

Comment: Yes, but... What i want is ADD the key. Doing what you mentioned, I would just set the value of "inventory.3", but I would still need to set it, which would be unfeasible if there were a user with many items.

Comment: If you don't have unique keys for the items, use an array. Or is there any reason that it has to be an object? Then you could just `....inventory.push("banana")`

Comment: Yes, have a reason. The reason: basically, the items that are purchased at the bot's "store" are objects too. What I want is to add these objects to the inventory's object.

Comment: Can you use the id's of the items as keys?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. How's that? Like `inventory.iten1 = itens[iten]`?

PS: `itens[]` = the object that represents all items. `item` = the item that the user wants to buy.

Comment: And how does the structure of `item` look like? Or is it really just a `string`?

Comment: Basically, the `iten` structure is:
`let iten = message.content.slice(5);
`
PS: this means that the `string` item is everything that is said after the first 5 letters of the command (which are ";buy "), including spaces.

Comment: basically, you should re-think your structure. but you could generate a random id with this one-liner: `btoa(Math.random())`

Comment: And what is the id for, exactly?

Comment: The `1` for `'melon'` in your example